# How to make these Jquery tabs linkable through ahref?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I've been trying to fix this all day - so rest assured that I've come here after exhausting all of my limited capabilities. I'm no programmer by any means, but I have attempted..

I'm running WordPress and using a theme which has custom tabs.

I want to be able to link to the tabs using ahref code. E.g. www.test.com/page/#tab2 and have it open the second tab.

**Here's the HTML code:**

```
 <div class="short-tabs">
 <ul style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dbd6d6;">
<li><a href="">Best Food Processors</a></li>
<li><a href="">Buying Guide</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div style="border: none;">
 this is tab1
 </div>
 <div style="border: none;">
 this is tab2
 </div>
 </div>
```

**Here's the JQUERY code that corresponds to it:**

```
    // Tabbed blocks
    jQuery(".short-tabs").each(function () {
        var thisel = jQuery(this);
        thisel.children("div").eq(0).addClass("active");
        thisel.children("ul").children("li").eq(0).addClass("active");
    });

    jQuery(".short-tabs > ul > li a").click(function () {
        var thisel = jQuery(this).parent();
        thisel.siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
        thisel.addClass("active");
        thisel.parent().siblings("div.active").removeClass("active");
        thisel.parent().siblings("div").eq(thisel.index()).addClass("active");
        return false;
    });
```

I have no idea how to edit this to allow for linking to and from the tabs. As you can see from the HTML, I don't even need to link to #tab1 for example for them to work.

Any ideas or experts who can help? :)

**JSFIDDLE Link:**
http://jsfiddle.net/cws1j0q7/2/

Comment: could you provide your example in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I've made one, not sure which JS is relevant to this: http://jsfiddle.net/cws1j0q7/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can check the URL hash using `window.location.hash`

The easiest way for example to integrate this into your code is to add the *href* to your links

```
<ul style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dbd6d6;">
     <li>
        <a href="#tab1">Best Food Processors</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#tab2">Buying Guide</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

check if the URL has a hash and trigger the click

```
if(window.location.hash){
    $('a[href=' + window.location.hash + ']').trigger('click');
}
```

You can also set a data-* attribute or an ID and check for that. Make sure you disable auto-scrolling if you choose to set an ID.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I have no idea where to include the JS. I've added the href's to the tabs. Do I just paste your JS into my JS file?

I also want it so that I can link to the tabs. E.G. In tab 1 I will put, "Click here to go to <a href="dasda.com/asd/#tab2"> which will then move the browser to tab2. 

Here's my example: http://www.kitchenvoice.com/396-2/

Answer (score 0):

The key here is `window.location.hash`

```
jQuery(".short-tabs").each(function () {
    var thisel = jQuery(this);
    thisel.children("div").eq(0).addClass("active");
    thisel.children("ul").children("li").eq(0).addClass("active");
});

jQuery(".short-tabs > ul > li a").click(function () {
    selectTab(this);
    return false;
});

jQuery("a").click(function () {
    processHash( '#' + jQuery(this).prop('href').split("#")[1] );
});

function selectTab($a) {
    var $li = jQuery($a).parent();
    $li.siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
    $li.addClass("active");
    $li.parent().siblings("div.active").removeClass("active");
    $li.parent().siblings("div").eq($li.index()).addClass("active");
}

function processHash(hash) {
    var $a = jQuery('.short-tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]');
    selectTab( $a );
}

if ( window.location.hash ) {
    processHash();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cws1j0q7/7/

Comment: Got that working with URL's, but a href links still don't work if you check the example link on the page.

Comment: Your code is completely obfuscated by your autoptimize plugin so I can't really see what you are doing wrong.  Can you temporarily disable this plugin?

Comment: I've fixed it by using: <a href="#noob" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">new test</a>

Would love to know if you have a better option!

Comment: Updated my answer with new code to accomodate same page links

Comment: I'm getting weird results. Check this: http://www.kitchenvoice.com/food-processor-reviews/breville-bfp800xl-review/

The #comm tab doesn't work, and URL links now don't work. For example: http://www.kitchenvoice.com/food-processor-reviews/breville-bfp800xl-review/#specs